# php xpath: query within a query result

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to parse an html file.

The idea is to fetch the span's with `title` and `desc` classes and to fetch their information in each div that has the attribute class='thebest'.

here is my code:

```
<?php

$example=<<<KFIR
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="a">moshe1
<div class="aa">haim</div>
 </div>
 <div class="a">moshe2</div>
 <div class="b">moshe3</div>

<div class="thebest">
<span class="title">title1</span>
<span class="desc">desc1</span>
</div>
<div class="thebest">
span class="title">title2</span>
<span class="desc">desc2</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
KFIR;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($example);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$expression="//div[@class='thebest']";
$arts = $xpath->query($expression);

foreach ($arts as $art) {
    $arts2=$xpath->query("//span[@class='title']",$art);
    echo $arts2->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $arts2=$xpath->query("//span[@class='desc']",$art);
    echo $arts2->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
echo "done";
```

the expected results are:

```
title1desc1title2desc2done
```

the results that I'm receiving are:

```
title1desc1title1desc1done
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make the queries relative... start them with a dot (e.g. `".//…"`).

```
foreach ($arts as $art) {
    // Note: single slash (direct child)
    $titles = $xpath->query("./span[@class='title']", $art);
    if ($titles->length > 0) {
        $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $title;
    }

    $descs = $xpath->query("./span[@class='desc']", $art);
    if ($descs->length > 0) {
        $desc = $descs->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo $desc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the second query try `textContent`

```
foreach ($arts as $art) {
    echo $art->textContent;
}
```

`textContent` returns the text content of this node and its descendants.

As an alternative, change the XPath to

```
$expression="//div[@class='thebest']/span[@class='title' or @class='desc']";
$arts = $xpath->query($expression);

foreach ($arts as $art) {
    echo $art->nodeValue;
}
```

That would fetch the span children of the divs with a class thebest having a class of title or desc.